# Borrar duplicados y luego ordenar Array en Javascritpt

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for

Recién estoy empezando en Javascript y tengo el siguiente array:

```
var numeros : [4,0,3,4,7,5,3,8,1,2,3,4,4,0,7,3,9,6,2,1]
```

Me esta dando dolor de cabeza por el simple hecho que he intentado muchas cosas y aún no me esta dando.

Tengo que borrar primero los duplicados y luego ordenar, he probado con un for más el metodo pop y fuera del bucle poniendo un sort, pero nada.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Saludos. Da un vistazo a https://lodash.com/ hay documentación https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15 es una libreria muy buena con distintas cosas para procesar arreglo de datos nativos y objetos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta seria una respuesta con javascript puro que borra duplicados y ordena:

```js
var numeros = [4,0,3,4,7,5,3,8,1,2,3,4,4,0,7,3,9,6,2,1];
//con la funcion set quitamos los elementos duplicados del array
let array_sin_duplicados = [...new Set(numeros)];
//con la funcion sort lo ordenamos de menor a mayor.
tuarrayquebuscas=array_sin_duplicados.sort();
// con document write visualizamos el resultado en el body de tu html
document.write(tuarrayquebuscas);
```

Comment: Estoy cursando DAW y llevo literal 3 clases. Merci por comentar el código.

Answer (score 0):

Pues algo simple puede ser algo como esto:

```
var tuArray = [4,0,3,4,7,5,3,8,1,2,3,4,4,0,7,3,9,6,2,1]; //tus números
var individuales = tuArray.filter(function(item, index, array) {
      return array.indexOf(item) === index;
    })
    console.log(individuales.sort());
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Llevo 4 clases y se me escapa el filter y su función, pero muchas gracias.